# What is the advantage of expiring close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Why do close votes expire after some time? To me this concept seems to have mostly disadvantages. Just because some time passed, why should the system or I have changed my mind about the off-topicness of a question?

I understand that for frequently viewed/voted questions it makes little sense to keep close votes around forever. But most questions are viewed very rarely. The current system seems to make it virtually impossible for non-moderators to close such questions.

Wouldn't it make sense to make the close vote removal script context dependent? A very simple heuristic would be checking the voting pattern and only remove close votes if there has been progress (views/upvotes/flags/answers etc). In my opinion it only makes sense to remove close votes if many people viewed the question and decided that it is not so bad after all.

Comment: What's the value in keeping a close vote in on a question that people may see, but ultimately decide that it's alright enough to stick around?

Comment: @Makoto, yes but I guess that's my point. Only in this case it makes sense to remove the close vote.

Comment: Can you provide scenarios in which this isn't the case?  My understanding of the system was that it was capable of doing this.

Comment: @Makoto, I just looked through my list of close votes and it seems that all expire after a fixed time.

Comment: MSE: [Why do close votes expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire)

Comment: If you are close voting in low traffic tags you can leave a cv-pls in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room,

Comment: @rene, yes this is an option, but rather inconvenient.

Comment: We have a [userscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js) that adds a cv-pls link next to the close link ;)

Comment: @rene, yes this is very convenient. We have that in the python channel as well. I myself rarely post questions to close though.

Comment: If close votes were indefinite, then *eventually* pretty much every question could be closed. It takes 1 close vote every year or two and you're done. And you can't *counter* vote. If somebody close voted, it's not possible to say to the system "I disagree with closing this" until it's actually closed. So, if you limit the life of a close vote, you ensure that questions stay open when there clearly isn't enough interest in closing them.

Comment: @VLAZ Not that we need to debate a 3 year old proposal, but it does seem like they considered that. In their system, positive interactions like views, upvotes, and answers would lead to the gradual removal of close votes.

Comment: @VLAZ On the flip side, there are lots of *horrible* questions which get 3 or 4 close votes, but never get closed because not enough users with the privilege and willingness to VTC see it in a sufficiently small time period, simply because the question doesn't get enough attention. Consider a question with 25 views and 4 close votes after a week. If it doesn't get closed via (overwhelmed) close review, odds are it'll stay open forever (unless there's a coordinated effort by SOCVR or meta), even if high-rep users who stumble on the question in the future VTC.

Comment: Close votes should automatically expire via *some* mechanism, but *time* isn't the right measure IMO. View count, or view count by 3k+ rep (or something of the sort) would make much more sense IMO

Comment: @divibisan Doh! I didn't look at the dates. The was apparently edited, so it showed up as "active", when it wasn't really.

Comment: @CertainPerformance absolutely this goes the other way too - some questions don't get closed when they should be. [The recent experiement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) does indicate that we should be closing more than what we currently are. And part of the problem is that 5 votes is too many for some low-viewed questions. However, at least currently the system helps questions with more views to stay open. This is better than trickle-vote closing popular questions. We need more balance, though.

Comment: @CertainPerformance expiration is already a function of view count [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/165773). Votes on questions with over 100 views expire much faster (4 days instead of 14)

Answer (score 4):

As a close voter, I appreciate expiration because it lets me re-submit the troublesome question into review queue if prior round didn't satisfy me (FWIW same logic applies to reopen votes). If a question wasn't closed (reopened) in review, expiration allows me trigger repeat review after 18 or 28 days [depending on views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/165773).

This was explained in details a while ago [at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/165773):

> Remember [the original problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags) that the 100-view threshold was intended to address? Well, what happens *today* if you find a seriously problematic question in the obscure tag that you follow, you vote to close it, and... Nothing happens. Maybe your vote hangs around forever, or maybe enough random viewers trickle in from Google to hit the view threshold and your vote ages away.
>
> What can you do? Not much. You can't *re-cast* a pending vote, and you can't re-cast an *aged* vote. Your proposed closure was put before the committee and... ignored. Maybe there were a lot of parking tickets that day.
>
> Some folks raise a flag when this happens, but moderators are often reluctant to intervene on topics they aren't personally familiar with unless the problem is *truly egregious* - they signed up to be exception-handlers after all, and a question *no one cares about* isn't all that exceptional. Others lean on the Very Low Quality flag to give questions a second shot at review - but strictly-speaking, this is an abuse of VLQ and will probably get harder as we continue to develop review.
>
> What you'd *like* to be able to do, upon coming across a problematic question you've previously voted to close, is just bump it back into the close queue. Once upon a time, this was actually the *recommended* way to handle vote aging on questions if you kept tripping over them - but at some point, it was disabled, probably because folks abused it to keep harping on some personal annoyance.

I happened to be around prior to expiration was introduced and I can personally confirm observations made above. It was real pain to stumble across some old question that you voted close or reopen a while ago and be unable to normally vote again.

It was quite a relief when expiry was introduced and all these pains just went away.