# Voting to re-open your own closed question?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, reopen-closed

A fairly controversial post was made and an close/open/delete war happened. During one of the rounds of opening, the original poster was involved in casting a re-open vote.  Is this intended behavior? If so, is there specific reasoning why one is able to cast a reopen vote on their own post?  At a surface level this appears to go against some of the precedent of other privileges.  We don't give users full control over deleting their own posts (at least one positively up-voted answer, un-deleting). Voting to re-open your own post appears like it would be disallowed along these same lines, even if it still needs the help of others. But maybe it's different.  I'm wondering if there was at one time a discussion over the ability to self open, and what those arguments where.

EDIT: I should add that while some people may think that having 4 people review it is still enough, when the new 3 vote system comes in place, this becomes effectively 2 other people.  SO did not always have 5 votes to open/close either, so I'm wondering if this came up in the previous long term 3 vote implementation.

Comment: A user can cast a close or open vote on their own posts.  This has been the behavior for *quite* a while.  If they were a diamond moderator, I believe the convention is for them not to moderate their own posts; if it's the case that someone has a gold badge and they want to reopen their question which was marked as a dupe, they could (and that *might* be but seldom *is* cause for suspicion).  Otherwise, they'd need four other people to agree with them, and then **the system would just work** if four others don't.

Comment: @Makoto Won't the new changes make it so only two people need to agree with them?

Comment: ...yes, but the system would *still* work if two others didn't.  Not seeing a problem.

Comment: @Makoto I'm talking about if two others *did* and the OP voted to re-open.

Comment: I'm not seeing that as a circumstance *too* far removed from if four people + OP reopened the question.  If it turns into a game of ping-pong with teams of people closing and reopening, get a diamond moderator involved.  Otherwise, it's likely not a hill worth dying on.

Comment: @Makoto in this case it appeared the diamond moderators were *also* engaging in open-closing/deleting/undeleting.

Comment: That’s what diamond moderators do, @opa.

Comment: If you want to discuss 5 vs 3 votes you're better of [doing so here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) rather than trying to change this question to encompass that too.

Comment: @RobertLongson I had assumed it was still in effect until some one mentioned it took 4 votes

Comment: @RobertLongson [yeah I know](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390101/2036035)

Comment: @CodyGray I was stating that Moderators were engaging in the same kind of battle that close war people did, not that one moderator made a unilateral decision to either open or close.

Comment: I don’t understand what that means. Moderators don’t have to battle; all our votes are binding, so it always results in a unilateral open or close. We try to respect the community in exercising that power, and generally won’t override the community for Q&A on main, but Meta is a different place.

Comment: @CodyGray I mean two different moderators having two different opinions on what should happen, and taking two contradicting actions.

Comment: We do seem to be getting somewhat away from the original question here though. Perhaps you'd be better off asking a new question about moderator individuality and question battles with reference to that specific question. They are allowed to be human and have opinions you know.

Comment: Heh... If I’m guessing correctly about the “controversial” question that you’re thinking of, it’s important to mention that there is a difference between Stack Overflow employees and community moderators. Both carry diamonds, but there may well be differences of opinion between them. Besides what Robert said about moderators being human and having different opinions. We do have a smoke-filled room where we can discuss confidential matters, but we don’t really use it as often as people might think. Far too many flags for that. We just each use our best judgment.

Answer (score 7):

Voting to reopen your own closed post [is indeed a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

And you're right they don't get full control over reopening because they need another 4 people (or one gold badge holder) to reopen, but they can kick the process off and put their post in the reopen queue. Hopefully they addressed whatever issues it had before doing that.

Comment: Also worth noting that folks only get one vote, so this is not an avenue towards a “war” or “ping-pong”.

Answer (score 3):

Users are able to cast both close and open votes on their own questions as long as they have the privilege and since both of those votes require others to agree with them there are checks in place to make sure the action is correct.

Users also are only allowed to cast a single open vote on a question so that if it gets closed again they are not able to vote to re-open it a secon time. This was mentioned by Cody Gray in a comment on another answer.

Moderators who have more expanded powers that let them open a post on their own generally don't cast votes on their own questions.